# To Extract .7zip file using SharpCompress library in windows phone but getting exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

```cs
IArchive archive = null;
IReader reader = null;
archive = SevenZipArchive.Open(fileStream, Options.LookForHeader);

reader = archive.ExtractAllEntries();            
while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
{
    if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
    {
        Stream _redaer = new MemoryStream();
        reader.WriteEntryTo(_redaer);
        fileName = reader.Entry.FilePath;
        int index = fileName.LastIndexOf("/");
        string file = fileName.Substring(index + 1, (fileName.Length - (index + 1)));
        using (binaryReader = new BinaryReader(_redaer, encoding))
        {
            long fileLength = _redaer.Length;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            _redaer.Position = 0;
            _redaer.CopyTo(ms);
            byte[] buteArray = ms.ToArray();
            SaveToIsoStore(fileName, buteArray);
        }
    }
}
```

This code gives exception of type SharpCompress.Common.InvalidFormatException,Please provide the solution in wp7.